# Перегрузка бинарного "-" почему не работает

Tags: c++, visual-c++, перегрузка-операторов

Нужно было перегрузить минус так, чтобы вычитал элемент массива с определенным индексом, что не так? Постоянно выдает ошибки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
class MyArray
{
    int *numbers;
    int sizeOfArray;
public:
    MyArray()       
    {
        sizeOfArray = 0;   
        numbers = 0;
    }
    MyArray(int size)      
    {
        sizeOfArray = size;
        numbers = new int [sizeOfArray];
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    ~MyArray()      
    {
        delete [] numbers;
    }
    void showData()         //вывод данных массива на экран
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            cout << numbers[i] << " | ";
        }
    cout << endl << endl;
    }
    int& operator[](int j)
    {
        return numbers[j];
    };
    `
friend MyArray operator -(size_t index);
};
    MyArray& operator-(size_t index) 
{ 
    int n = 5;
    for (int i = index; i < n; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
    }
    --n;
    return *this; 
}`
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    MyArray ArrayInt(5);   
    ArrayInt[0] = 1; //перегруженный []
    ArrayInt[1] = 2;
    ArrayInt[2] = 3;
    ArrayInt[3] = 4;
    ArrayInt[4] = 5;
    `ArrayInt(5) - ArrayInt[3];`
    cout << "Массив ArrayInt:  ";
    ArrayInt.showData();  
    return 0;
}
```

[image: jошибки]

Comment: что за ошибки то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
    int& operator[](int j)
    {
        return numbers[j];
    };

    MyArray& operator -(size_t index);
};

MyArray& MyArray::operator-(size_t index)
{
    for (int i = index; i < sizeOfArray-1; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
    }
    sizeOfArray--;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    MyArray ArrayInt(5);
    ArrayInt[0] = 1; //перегруженный []
    ArrayInt[1] = 2;
    ArrayInt[2] = 3;
    ArrayInt[3] = 4;
    ArrayInt[4] = 5;
    ArrayInt - 3;
    cout << "Массив ArrayInt:  ";
    ArrayInt.showData();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!
Спасибо, правда, что помогли такой тупой как хлебушку <3